# HDD bad sector marking through LUKS2 layer (dm-crypt) + ZFS

Tags: zfsonlinux, luks, bad-blocks

If having 2x LUKS-encrypted HDDs with a ZFS mirror pool on top of the dm-crypt mapper devices: what happens if one of my HDDs encounters an error and the OS recognizes a sector as bad ?

Will this bad sector information be passed to the encryption-layer and as such be there on the mapper device marked 'bad' as well ? (The corresponding-affected block of course).

(So that the ZFS layer on top of the encrypted device can see this and correct the error via internal mechanisms during access or during a scrubbing. No ZFS encryption - by intention. Yet).

Debian/Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a sector goes bad, LUKS would return an error - which will be corrected by ZFS (thanks to the other mirror leg).

If a sector return bad data, LUKS can decrypt an incorrect payload - which will be again correct by ZFS (thanks to checksum *and* mirroring).

In other words: with a ZFS mirror your data should be safe, unless *both* mirror legs are corrupted.

Comment: Does dm-integrity (actually used as a '--integrity xx' option for luks) make any sense, knowing ZFS is going to go on top of LUKS ? Or doesn't matter in this context really ? Would you 'cryptsetup luksformat' with or without it ?

Comment: No, I would not use dm-integrity with ZFS as the latter already has strong checksumming. dm-integrity can be useful with filesystems that do not checksum data, as ext4 and xfs.